# how to solve Non Static method in php 5.5 yii framework

Tags: php, yii

This is large application working fine online,
I am trying to use download all the file and configure it in local machine, 
I successfully download and configure 
But I stuck on this point, where error is 
`Non-static method Video::getVideoDetails() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

As over Stackoverflow question, I get some clue to remove `E_Strict` from `error_reporting` 
I used `E_ALL`. but the error is still there

here is the part of code

```
foreach($modelvideo as $bannerVideo):
         $videoTitle=Video::getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
         $videoDirector=Video::getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
         ?>
             <div class = 'item'>
```

I am not the php developer,
I really appreciate if you find easily way to solve this issue.

thanks

Comment: put the cod from model `Video` in the question -> you will find in models folder Video.php

Comment: this video.php file have around 858 line of code, cant be able to paste over here.

Comment: then find and post the cod from `getVideoDetails` and `getDirector` or add video code to http://pastebin.com/ and add link here.

Comment: this is video.php http://pastebin.com/incaJ8xs

Comment: code looks like view not model and not contain getVideoDetails. is not the video model in this file. find something like this `class Video extends....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the lines from these

```
foreach($modelvideo as $bannerVideo):
         $videoTitle=Video::getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
         $videoDirector=Video::getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
         ?>
             <div class = 'item'>
```

to

```
foreach($modelvideo as $bannerVideo):
        $video = new Video();
         $videoTitle=$video->getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
         $videoDirector=$video->getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
         ?>
             <div class = 'item'>
```

`getVideoDetails` and `getVideoDetails` are static functions and depend only `$bannerVideo->id` and `$banner->user_id` respectively. Alternatively you can declare them to be static function by changing

```
public  function getVideoDetails
```

to

```
 public static function getVideoDetails
```

in the model function, However this will affect other places were the functions are called, so unless you know what you are doing don't change the model.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following  exact line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Make sure you do not have `;` before the above statement. which comments the line
Also you can turn off the errors from displaying.

```
display_errors = On
```

The above tricks will only make the application work but the problem still exists until you correct static calls to non static calls in all over the application.

```
$videoTitle=Video::getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
$videoDirector=Video::getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
```

to

```
$video = new Video();
$videoTitle=$video->getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
$videoDirector=$video->getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
```

Or the otherway by making those functions static. But that is somewhat risky. Because there might be having `$this->` calls within the function which generates errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also the following code:

```
foreach($modelvideo as $bannerVideo):
         $videoTitle=Video::getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
         $videoDirector=Video::getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
         ?>
             <div class = 'item'>
```

can be converted to:

```
foreach($modelvideo as $bannerVideo):
         $videoTitle=(New Video())->getVideoDetails($bannerVideo->id);
         $videoDirector=(New Video())->getDirector($bannerVideo->user_id);
         ?>
             <div class = 'item'>
```